# Kafka how to prevent using old records when joining multiple streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

i'm fairly new to kafka and trying to join bunch of streams on a unique key. I have two different streams that i get from listening on two different topics. I repartition and join them by their corresponding keys. Then, i listen on another topic C, and join the previous joined data with the fresh streamC. So, to sum it up

```
A-B=>AB
C->
AB-C>ABC
```

This works and joins the data exactly as i want and i'm happy about it. For some reason, if there is only data coming to topic C let's say, it'll take the data from state store (I believe it writes the previous data to a state store). Thus, it'll accomplish the join with the old record. From what i understand, kafka has sort of it's own caching mechanism with the state store so it makes it more efficient but in my case my data is pretty dynamic and changes, so i don't want it to use old records for joining. Essentially, what i want is only join these data if all of these topics got a new payload separately and each of them also finishes their own join. - not using any previous record in any case.

Here's the related code

```
protected Topology createStreamTopology(){

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();


        //Stream A
        KStream<String, A> streamA = builder.stream(
                aTopic,
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), aSerde)
        ).selectKey((k, v) -> A.getOrderId(v));


        //Stream B
        //Make a table of the salesforce order line item events
        KStream<String, B> streamB = builder.stream(
                bTopic,
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), bSerde)
        ).filter(
                (k1, v1) -> v1.getPayload().getPlatformC() != null
        ).selectKey(
                (k, v) -> v.getOrder()
        );


        //Join stream a and stream b
        KStream<String, AB> abData = streamA.join(
                streamB,
                joinedAB::new,
                JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(2)),
                Joined.with(Serdes.String(), aSerde, bSerde)
        ).selectKey(
                (k, v) -> v.getPayload.getUniqueID());  


        // Stream c
        KStream<String, C>stream streamC=builder.stream(cTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), serde))
                .mapValues((k,v)->transformToC(v))
                .filter((key, value) -> Objects.nonNull(value))
                .selectKey((key, value) -> value.getID());


        //join stream c and joined abData
        KStream<String, abcData> abcData = streamC.join(
                abData,
                joinedABC::new,
                JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(2)),
                Joined.with(Serdes.String(), cSerde, abSerde)
        );
}
```